# How to filter messages that I want to send to SQS - AWS Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, dead-letter

I have a Lambda function to send messages from a SQS deadletter to another SQS, but now I want to customize it, where I can specificate the range of the dates, type, another among, maybe from AWS CLI where I can specificate the **configuration test event**. Exist a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using lambda function which will first read SQS messages from queue1 and you can use that and  customize (add your logic of addition of strings/dates) and then write to SQS queue 2 from your lambda function.